# How can I set page size using WkHtmlToXSharp?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, itext

I was looking for an option to set a page size (of the pdf) while using WkHtmlToXSharp.
Currently the PDF auto generate A4 pages , but my HTML is long and I wish to generate 1 long continues PDF file.

Is that possible ? How?

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change Page size like..

```
 ........your code.....
 Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3,8f, 8f, 8f, 8f);
 PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
 ...................................
```